# If an item is too powerful to repair, am I screwed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a bow that has Power IV, Flame II, Punch II, and Infinity I, and also it's renamed. According to the wiki, that has a base value of 38. Since the max level is 39, that would mean practically anything I want to do is above the max. Is there any way to repair it?

Comment: Just for future reference, it gets more and more expensive to repair an item every time you repair it with an anvil. However, if you re-name items, this penalty is removed. Remember to name your tools early to keep the repair costs low.

Comment: @IQAndreas, is that a bug or intended behavior?

Comment: @IQAndreas Clarification: once you rename an item the penalty is reset. It doesn't matter how many times an item was repaired before it was renamed; it's merely that every repair (but the first) you do before renaming is more expensive than it would have been if you renamed it first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can repair the bow without using an anvil, but you'd lose the enchantments. I'm afraid that without mods you won't be able to repair your bow, use it wisely :-(

Comment: There is [Better Anvils](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1576006-152better-anvils-removes-the-level-limit/) for 1.5.2 that does exactly and only this, but who knows when it will update for 1.6.2.

Comment: man sorry, but repairing a bow and losing it's enchants is absolutely useless as it becomes totally different item. This should have been a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 14):

As fredley stated, you cannot repair it in game. But since you asked for ANY way to repair it, you could use [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) to set the damage of your bow to 0.

Simple open the `level.dat` file inside the folder of your world with NBTExplorer and klick `Search->Find`. Tick the two checkboxes and search for name:"id" and value:"261".

This will quickly show your bow, now you just have double-click "Damage" and enter 0.

That's it, your bow is saved ;) ( btw: that's an awesome bow! )

[image: Little Showcase]

Comment: If you're willing to use this method, you may as well set it to a high negative value, so that it lasts even longer.

Comment: High negative or low negative? The highest negative is -1 (or, arguably, 0).

Comment: Low negative, say -1000. If you use the bow once, the damage will be -999, so you can use it very often without draining the damage-bar on it.

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.9, you can get the Mending enchantment, which repairs it automatically while getting experience. Be careful though, this is a treasure enchantment, so you may only get it only through fishing, buying from villagers, or from chests in Generated Structures.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to cheat, (And it's on single player) just click open to LAN and turn on cheats, then do "/gamemode 1" then you can repair it for free.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this yet, just in Idea stage right now, but maybe if you put a regular bow in the first slot and add the enchanted bow to it, it would only have been worked one time, so I would think you would be able to work on it more. It would be as if you had combined all the books and then put it on a bow. (Just ifs though)