# How do I bypass the to expensive error in the minecraft anvil?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, cheats

How do I bypass the to expensive error in the minecraft anvil? I can never get all the enchantments on my sword and i was wondering if i could bypass this somehow. I believe this effects all versions of minecraft but i need to know how to get around this for minecraft java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass the "too expensive" cap for the anvil in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/328386/how-can-i-bypass-the-too-expensive-cap-for-the-anvil-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 3):

There may not be a way to bypass the "Too Expensive!" warning, but you can work around it by anviling with a cheaper method. Using this method, it is theoretically possible to apply up to 30 enchantments to something.

The method works like this: Lets say you have a Sharpness V, Looting III, Sweeping Edge III, Mending, Unbreaking III, and Knockback II book.

Let's call these books with only 1 enchantment Book1. Next, combine a Book1 with another Book1 to get a Book2. Book2 should have 2 enchants on them. Repeat these steps:

Book1 + Book1 = Book2

Book2 + Book2 = Book3

Book3 + Book3 = Book4

etc

---

If this is unclear, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMDYntXnKSQ) does a great job explaining.

Answer (score 3):

If you drop your item on the ground and run the command:
`/data merge entity @e[type=item,distance=..3,limit=1,sort=nearest] {Item:{tag:{RepairCost:0}}}`, when you pick up the item, it should have the repair cost reset.

Answer (score 1):

The "Too Expensive" warning cannot be bypassed but it doesn't actually cost infinite levels, just a relatively high amount being over 50 or around there. If you are willing to grind some levels using a mob farm or something you can still get all the enchantments on your sword. otherwise you can use the method that @ginkgo suggested.

Comment: This is false, I've just tested it on version 1.16.2 by giving myself 100 levels and not being able to max out a netherite sword, I managed to get all but one of the books applied. I also tried it with 2,147,483,647 levels, the maximum, and still could not do it in survival

Comment: @Macks: Combine: [Diamond sword + Mending] [Sweeping edge II + Unbreaking III] [Looting III + Knockback II] [Curse of Vanishing + Fire aspect II]  [Sharpness V + Looting/Knockback] [Sword + Curse/FireAsp] [Sword + Sharp/Loot/Knock] [Sword + Sweep/Unbreak]. The last operation costs 18 levels, meaning you could still apply more enchantments if they were compatible or use anvil to repair at least 1 time. Of course you can't apply Smite or Bane of Anthropods together with Sharpness as they are mutually incompatible. And of course you can skip Curse of Vanishing if you don't play on Anarchy servers

Comment: @SF. I combined all the books separately to see if this solution was viable, obviously, you can combine all the books using that method, but this person said that you can bypass it by having 50 levels.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to bypass the "Too Expensive!" warning without mods [such as Anvil Fix](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/anvil-fix#:%7E:text=Anvil%20Fix%20removes%20the%20level,to%20combine%20in%20Survival%20mode.), unless you are in Creative mode. This applies to all editions of Minecraft.