# How do you enchant your weapons without hitting the "too expensive" thing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Some users have suggested [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/328386) question and answer, but that asks for an exploit, while I am asking for a way to not encounter this in the first place.

---

Ok, so we all know the infamous words, "too expensive". I think everyone who has played Minecraft knows what these words mean, and for those who don't, I'd advise you to try and not hit those words, because it makes your life harder. So I was looking around the Internet, and I found out that the anvil hits a certain level cap. And I'm trying to enchant my bow, but I don't know how to avoid those words. Is there a certain way to enchant a weapon so it doesn't become "too expensive"?

For those players who don't know what "too expensive" means, it's when you hit a certain upgrade cap (I don't really know what it's call, so ima call it upgrade cap) on an anvil. So when you use an anvil, each time you enchant a weapon of your chose, the XP requirement will keep getting higher until you hit the "too expensive mark. Even if you have enough XP, it will still say "too expensive", so enchant you gear WISELY.

Comment: This question very firmly needs more clarity. Please edit it to clarify what "Too Expensive" means for users who may not play Minecraft

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I bypass the "too expensive" cap for the anvil in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/328386/how-can-i-bypass-the-too-expensive-cap-for-the-anvil-in-minecraft)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an optimum enchantment strategy in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254360/is-there-an-optimum-enchantment-strategy-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it's how I avoid it.

Every act of enchanting adds an enchantment level to an item, every time you enchant *or repair* an item with a higher level. it becomes more expensive. I know of two things to avoid this

Start with good enchantments, don't work a fortune I into fortune II into fortune III
that takes too many enchantments, get a fortune III to start with, and add something else that's good.

second, the most important part, the game enchants to the highest enchantment level of an item +1. What you can do is start with a pickaxe that already has at least one high level enchantment on it and add a book to that. Your pickaxe is now Enchantment level(EC) 2,  Second. Get the next enchantment book, and enchant another book on that book, That book now has two enchantments and is level 2. Add that book to your pickaxe, making your EC3.
Next you can make a level three book and add that. And so on until you hit that "too expensive" level. However with some good enchanted books you can end up with some extremely good gear before reaching that limit.

so in short: start with good enchantments, combine enchanted books to the same level as the item you're enchanting before using them on that item.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your way when I get the chance to and I'll tell you how it went!

Answer (score 1):

[Is there an optimum enchantment strategy in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254360/is-there-an-optimum-enchantment-strategy-in-minecraft?rq=1) is an easy way to do so, this makes the enchanting process as efficient as can be.

Answer (score 0):

combine books in an orderly fashion, if you are trying to make a sharpness 5, fire aspect 3, unbreakable 3, mending 1 sword then mix the sharpness and fire aspect books, then the unbreaking and mending books, then put one book on the sword then the other...
-- should work --